# Regsrv32 error in win7 x64

Tags: dll, regsvr32

I installed EsetSmartSecurity, After update it found some threats. But now when I turn on computer receive this error.
[image]

And that .dll file was a threat that found.
[image]

What is happen? What program causes it? How I solve it?

Comment: No Idea for this problem??

Comment: I search and find ep0lvr1m.dll in my computer. I copy it in that folder. now I get new error!

Comment: Error: the module ...... was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "...." is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again. Help me!